# Return column index of a match

Tags: excel, indexing, find

I have a value stored in A1, and a reference array B2:C10. I want to get the column index which contains the value in A1 (unique). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a cell and then:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH($A$1,B1:B10,0),MATCH($A$1,C1:C10,0))
```

for example:

[image]

If you want to offset the **index** to the top of the table, just subtract **1** from the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want with the "MATCH()" function, but note that it returns the position within the range, not the absolute column number.

Have a look at:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010342679.aspx?CTT=1

Rob

Comment: Yes. But MATCH seems only look for value in 1 dimension, not 2

Comment: Ah. I missed that it was 2D. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

This is if you want the column number.

```
=IFERROR(COLUMN(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH($A$1,B:B, 0))), COLUMN(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH($A$1,C:C, 0))))
```